# Efficient way to check multiple variables declarations?

Tags: php, variables, isset

In a project of mine I am working with a sequence of pages that each give information that is used in the next, with POST and session variables. Simple example:

Page 1: enter name -> page 2 display name; ask birth date -> page 3 display name and birth date.

If a user goes directly to page 3 I want to display a message that s/he has not entered a name and/or birth date and should try again. Currently I am still doing it like so. On page 2:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

and page 3:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) $name = $_SESSION['name'];
if (isset($_POST['bday'])) $_SESSION['bday'] = $_POST['bday'];
```

as declarations and in the body an if-clause like

```
if (isset($name) && isset($_SESSION['bday'])) {
    // do main stuff
else {
    // display error message
}
```

The example is simple enough, but in the real world my code has a lot more variables and data from the forms, and putting all this first in variable assignments and then in an if-clause is tiring and seems not efficient to me. Is there a better, more straightforward way to check things like this? Or is what I posted the best, most-used way to go?

Comment: Using a ternary operator may help $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Please enter your name';

Comment: Create an array containing the variable names that are required until the given point and do the checks through some kind of iteration?

Comment: @NickG But that wouldn't really 'catch' the missing variable; you cannot allow or disallow functions like that.

Comment: Other idea, create an object with the form data as properties, with a method that validates if its properties are empty, and return the empty fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one call to isset to check several variables.

```
isset($_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['bday'], ...)
```

Or you can write your own function like

```
if (variablesFilled(['name', 'bday', ...])) { }

function variablesFilled($array) {
   foreach ($array as $entry) {
     if (!isset($_SESSION[$entry])) {
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to write some helper methods. One to rewrite `$_POST` data to `$_SESSION`, dumb as this:

```
function copyPostToSession(array $fields) {
    foreach($fields as $field) {
       if(isset($_POST[$field])) {
          $_SESSION[$field] = $_POST[$field];
       }
    }
}
```

so instead of `if` forest, you do:

```
copyPostToSession(array('name','bday'));
```

(additionally you can count how many fields were present and return `true` or `false` if there's mismatch) and the other (pretty similar) to check if you got all the required data in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: In helper methods like this, do I need to make `$_POST` and/or `$_SESSION` global inside the function? I tried Markus' function, which seems almost identical to yours, and I get a 500 internal server error. I put the helper function inside a separate file, if that matters.

Comment: Can be similar - hard to come originala in 3 lines. But mine aswer is 1 minute earlier :) As for $_SESSION and $_POST - these are superglobals visible everywhere. As for error 500 - check server logs

Comment: Yeah, problem is I can't check logs now so will have to do that when I get to work. It is strange though. I think the problem is that I try to assign the result to a variable, is that possible? Is it not possible to do do this? http://pastebin.com/V8e0xGqz

Comment: After testing this isn't the problem, the problem is with the function itself. See my comment to Markus' post.

Comment: You should not change question scope. You asked about `check multiple variables declarations` so accept answer that helped and ask another question related to your error 500 with use of included function

Comment: I never changed the scope of the question. Your answer didn't help and you didn't help me solve my issue - I got a 500 error when trying your solution. The problem was that my PHP version does not support the [] notation, and I should use array(). Add that to your post and I might add it as correct.

Comment: Your question does not show how you create arrays. Your code just reads. And you also did not mention you are on pre 5.4, so how anyone could know? Edited.

Comment: That's not how to present an array that way. `array()`

Answer (score 0):

PHP's **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function is a [variadric function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).
You can put as many arguments as you want:

```
isset($a, $b, $c)
```

...which translates to:

```
isset($a) && isset($b) && isset($c)
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Seperate functions tend to differ a bit on a per server case. You could try calculating the time to perform a function a large number of times and compare which is faster.

But, yeah, that looks like fairly fast code there.

Might be worth trying a switch case statement as an alternative perhaps?